# How to get rid of "Menu_HoverRoot(this) Object Expected" error in ASP.NET application (SharePoint 2007)

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have just deployed my ASP.NET/C# code to a sharepoint server and am getting this error when hoving over the menu:

Menu_HoverRoot(this) Object Expected

I have absolutely no idea what is causing it, but have seen other people with this problem, and it seems to be something with WebResource.axd.

Could someone help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a configuration issue on your server.

Try to uncheck the following property:

IIS - Website - Properties - Home Directory - Configuration - Application Extensions, edit .axd - "Verify that file exists"

[image]

Comment: Can't remember if this was the exact solution, but I know this is a possible solution.